# Remove hyperlink text from csv

Tags: microsoft-excel, bash, csv

I have a csv file (created in excel file) whose first 2 lines are somehow like this:

```
"=HYPERLINK(""https://some.url/browse/ISSUE-3146"", ""ISSUE-3146"")","Bug","Related Case : Some description ",0.0,0,0,0,0,115734.466,21505.476,0,85.693,21404.944,14.839,0,0,0,94029.214,199.776
"=HYPERLINK(""https://some.url/browse/ISSUE-3145"", ""ISSUE-3145"")","Bug","Another description",1.0,0,0,0,0,115224.32,21329.679,0,2248.391,18584.597,496.691,0,0,0,91695.307,2199.334
```

Unfortunately (for reasons beyond the scope of this question) this file will be handed over to me like this.

Can I remove using bash (or ansible) this part

```
HYPERLINK(""https://some.url/browse/ISSUE-3146"",
```

from each line?

i.e. I want each first column to be:

```
ISSUE-XXXX
```

Comment: Given you can easily edit .CSV in Notepad++, I'd use a macro in Notepad++ or multi-line delete, or replace with null...

Comment: thx but I am working in linux and this has to be scripted;

Comment: Is it always the first 2 lines you want to delete from every file? Not just the URL part? There are several regex's to match any URL in google...

Comment: No it will be an entire csv whose first column will be like this

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the first field with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/=HYPERLINK(""http[^,]*,//' /input/file > /output/file
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Take your data  and place it in a text file that you save as file-type *.csv*.</strike>

Double-click the file and Excel will open it like:

[image]

The data you want is in column **A**, but it is in *hyperlink* form.

Copy column **A** and *PasteSpecial Values* back onto column **A**

*(If you don't need the other columns, just delete them)*

Answer (score 0):

1. In the first column enter the text in A1
2. In the second column in B1 enter the formula =len(A1)
3. In the third column in C1 enter =find("/",A1)
4. In the fourth column D1=find("/",$A$1,(C1+1))
5. Copy D1 in E1,E2,E3,....etc.....right across.
6. When you get #Value Error Stop
7. In the column next to Error Cell enter =Right(A1,(B1-The last cell before Error))
8. Thus String is found after removing all unwanted "/" characters.

Formulas can be copied down the rows.
We can also use "ISNUMBER" function to check the condition and display the result.

I hope the reply may be found satisfactory.

Thanks.